# Comma separated output while doing JSON parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I am trying to parse the JSON value using the method below, I'm getting output as:

```
2017-03-28T13:07:46Z
,
rfw23wmnq4wd
```

But, I want to avoid the next line in the output, I expected the output to be

```
2017-03-28T13:07:46Z , rfw23wmnq4wd.
```

Completely new to ruby, please dont mind since it is very basic one

```
require 'json'
value = `curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/pageid/incidents.json -H "Authorization: OAuth APIKEY"`
#puts value
data_hash = JSON.parse(value).map {|h| [h["created_at"] , "," , h["id"]] }
puts data_hash
```

Also when I am trying to get the value of `body` , not getting nay output , please assist

```
{{“id":"920h1l69bqgy","components":[{"id":"230g793b5kry","page_id":"3h5p5rr839fk","group_id":"69pspx7kvhhj","created_at":"2016-08-11T12:20:00Z","updated_at":"2018-10-01T18:14:33Z","group":false,"name":"WEB APP","description":null,"position":4,"status":"operational","showcase":false,"only_show_if_degraded":false}],"created_at":"2018-10-01T17:18:59Z","impact":"minor","impact_override":null,"incident_updates":[{"id":"dwwk370t321t","incident_id":"920h1l69bqgy","affected_components":[{"code":"230g793b5kry","name":"EU CENTRAL(FRANKFURT) - WEB APP","old_status":"degraded_performance","new_status":"operational"}],"body":"All connectivity issues on the EU accounts have been resolved and the portals will now load without any hassles.","created_at":"2018-10-01T18:14:33.844Z","custom_tweet":null,"deliver_notifications":true,"display_at":"2018-10-01T23:44:33.844+05:30","status":"resolved","tweet_id":null,"twitter_updated_at":null,"updated_at":"2018-10-01T18:14:33.844Z","wants_twitter_update":false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use puts with an array, each element is printed in a newline, you can try print that way, using [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html):

```
JSON.parse(value).map {|h| puts "#{h['created_at']} , #{h['id']}" }
```

Comment: Thanks much , also I have added one more query above , can you help on that please

Comment: @KarthikrajSaravanan Stop editing and expanding the question with more requests after getting a satisfying answer on the first question.